Value of a specific series

Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

I've considered using Riemann's sum to prove this but the result gives me $\frac{\pi}{4}$ so I guess this method isnt working.

Can you edit your post showing how you tried to solve it with Riemann's sum? Maybe there's a mistake here...

Also, is the upper limit in the sum $+\infty$ or $n$? I think this is where is your mistake

You wrote it as a Riemann sum. But I think you use $n$ as the upper limit in the sum ($1$ in the integral). In your case you used
$$\int_0^1\frac 1{1+x^2} dx=\frac\pi4$$
If you let the upper limit to be infinity:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac 1{1+x^2} dx=\frac\pi2$$
